MongooseError: T he connection string is not valid
I have issue via connecting with database to my backend in mongodb compass database
I want to know what exactly the issue is there
MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.
    at Connection.openUri (D:\Microservices\Grocery_Online_Shopping_App\online_shopping_monolithic\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:694:11)
MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.
    at Connection.openUri (D:\Microservices\Grocery_Online_Shopping_App\online_shopping_monolithic\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:694:11)
connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.
    


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Pass the connection string to mongoose.connect(CONNECTION_STRING).
It is currently undefined, start by logging the value to the console.
If you're retrieving the connection string from environment variables, it's likely that the environment variables are not being loaded correctly.
